# Deploy rasa application to dokku (docker)

Tags: rasa

I would like to deploy my rasa application to Dokku (= heroku-like + docker).

For this, I added a `Dockerfile` into my application:

```
FROM rasa/rasa:latest-spacy-en

RUN rasa train --domain domain.yml --data data --out models

EXPOSE 5100

CMD [ "rasa", "run", "-m", "models", "--enable-api" ]
```

The rasa docker image is successfully retrieved but I got this error when executing the `rasa train` command:

```
Step 2/4 : RUN rasa train --data data
 ---> Running in f263870fd730
The config file 'config.yml' is missing mandatory parameters: 'policies'. Add missing parameters to config file and try again.
remote: The command '/bin/sh -c rasa train --data data' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I tried to create an explicit folder for the application with the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM rasa/rasa:latest-spacy-en

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN rasa train --domain domain.yml --data data --out models

EXPOSE 5100

CMD [ "rasa", "run", "-m", "models", "--enable-api" ]
```

But I got this error:

```
Step 2/7 : RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
 ---> Running in f78470eb6d93
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/src/app’: Permission denied
remote: The command '/bin/sh -c mkdir -p /usr/src/app' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Here is my `config.yml` file:

```
# Configuration for Rasa NLU.

# https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/nlu/components/
language: fr
pipeline: pretrained_embeddings_spacy

# Configuration for Rasa Core.
# https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/policies/
policies:
  - name: MemoizationPolicy
  - name: KerasPolicy
  - name: MappingPolicy
  - name: FormPolicy
```

Any ideas?

Thanks very much for your help!
Thierry

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you don't have permission to create a directory, you can try running as a root user in the Dockerfile? E.g.

```
FROM rasa/rasa:latest-spacy-en

USER root

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN rasa train --domain domain.yml --data data --out models

EXPOSE 5100

CMD [ "rasa", "run", "-m", "models", "--enable-api" ]
```

[We don't run as root by default](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile_pretrained_embeddings_spacy_en#L82), so that's why the user doesn't have permission to create the folder.